# display ec2.describe.instance.status 's parameters

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3, serverless-framework

i am writtnig a lambda function on serverless framework that resturns instance's status, i used boto3

```
describe_instance_status()
```

my code works fine, i get all the parameters, but i want to display just The state of the instance (pending | running | shutting-down).

here is my code :

```
 import json
 import boto3
 import logging
 import sys 
 import os
 import traceback

 # Import local dependencies sys.path.append('./site-packages')

 from botocore.exceptions import ClientError from pprint import pprint

 #setup simple logging for INFO logger = logging.getLogger() 
 logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

 from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


 def  instance_status(event, context):
  """Take an instance Id and return its status"""
 body = {}
 status_code = 200

 try:
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    r = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-070ad081'])
     body["message"] = str(r)
 except Exception as e:
     print(traceback.format_exc())
     status_code = 500
     body["message"] = str(e)
 #need a json body to return the status
 response = {
     "statusCode": status_code,
     "body": json.dumps(body)
 }  
 return response
```

Here is the http output :

```
{
"message": "{u'InstanceStatuses': [{u'InstanceId': 'i-070ad071', u'InstanceState': {u'Code': 16, u'Name': 'running'}, u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a', u'SystemStatus': {u'Status': 'ok', u'Details': [{u'Status': 'passed', u'Name': 'reachability'}]}, u'InstanceStatus': {u'Status': 'ok', u'Details': [{u'Status': 'passed', u'Name': 'reachability'}]}}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '35684bc5-2ab5-4225-8f8b-66bb217866f8', 'HTTPHeaders': {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server': 'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 26 Sep 2017 09:36:15 GMT'}}}"
}
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `str(r)` as it will turn it into a stringified representation of a Python dictionary.

```
try:
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    r = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=['i-070ad081'])
    # Use 'r' instead of 'str(r)'
    body["message"] = r
except Exception as e:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
    status_code = 500
    body["message"] = str(e)

# need a json body to return the status
response = {
  "statusCode": status_code,
  "body": json.dumps(body)
}  

return response
```